# Numbers of increasing squence using BIT

Tags: algorithm

For EX: A sequence is giving  `1 3 2 4` now i have to find the number of increasing sequences.
I came to know about BIT algorithm which is give me O(nlog<sub>2</sub>n) solution as compared to O(n<sup>2</sup>).
Code is as follow

```cpp
void update(int idx ,int val){
    while (idx <= MaxVal){
        tree[idx] += val;
        idx += (idx & -idx);
    }
}
```

To read

```cpp
int read(int idx){
    int sum = 0;
    while (idx > 0){
        sum += tree[idx];
        idx -= (idx & -idx);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I can't understand how [they](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) are using BIT algorithms can you please help me

Comment: So the problem is to find the number of increasing sequences in a given sequence of numbers? Also when you say `I can't understand how they are using BIT algorithms`, you should make it clear who `they` are/is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary indexed tree's `read` function will return the number of values which is equals or less than `idx`.

So, by insert each element one by one, from 0 to n (n is number of elements)

- For each element, we need to know how many values that are less than this current element, and has already added to the BIT. Assume that this number is x, so the number of increasing sequence that end at this element is 2^x
- After calculating all sequences that ended at this element, we need to add this element into BIT

Pseudo code:

```
long result = 0;
BIT tree = //initialize BIT tree
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int number = tree.read(data[i] - 1);// Get the number of element that less than data[i];
    result += 1L<< number;
    tree.update(data[i], 1);

}
```

As update and read function has O(log n) time complexity, the above algo has time complexity O(n log n)

Comment: Is bit tree is initilized prior the for loop ? could you explain how you initialize BIT tree

Comment: @user4213270 yes, it is initialized prior, how to initialize BIT ? nothing special, just create an empty BIT.